# Android How to handle multiple instances data/identities and JNI

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

This is a question of good practice and a smart solution, I need an advice.

I have an app that (and as far as I can read here in Stackoverflow and by Google search):

- **The app handles kind of documents and I like it possible to
  handle more than one document at the same time**. (I am used to Win32 where there is a program segment and one segment of data for each instance but that is obviously not the case in Android/Java.)
- I see one instance starting the app from the app storage (the tablet) another opening a Gmail or email with an appended document file, a third instance by opening a file from a File handling app like ES file explorer. And I like them all be possible to be flipped in between. The user might like to read more than one document at a time. (correct me if I use the word instance wrong in the Android/Java environment)
- **The app is built in a JNI section that contains all the data and logics and a Java Android user interface.** (The JNI section is designed to be OS independent for implementations in different OS, has a glue c-file.)
- The Android section recreates every time the screen is flipped or instances are flipped between
- There is only one JNI instance and that is kept even when the Android Java part is recreated and all Java data is wiped out, right now it shows the last read file in all cases flipping in-between pushing the running app button
- **There are no problems making different instances within the JNI section as long as it is possible to bind them to each Java instance**, with an identity or something that I can use as a parameter in the interchange with the JNI section, **but how**?
- I can't save for instance the FilePathName in each instance to identify the instance in the Java section because it will be wiped when the Java section is recreated.

First question is if I am right in my observations reading Stackoverflow and Googled articles?

**Second question, any good suggestions in solving the issue?** I need an advice

- Is there a possibility to identify the instance in all situations as long it is alive?
- Any other possible paths, both to the general issue of separating data for each instance or identifying the instances for the JNI to handle the data for each instance?

Comment: Is it good practice to tag the intent with the file name opened by the instance of the intent? Like `getIntent().putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, FilePathName);` and by resume `Bundle  extras =  getIntent().getExtras();`? I tried with counters but they are reset by the repeated recreations of the Java section.  The FilePathName is actually something that can be stored in the JNI and handed to the JNI on the onResume. Or are there any better suggestions?

Comment: A counter of each intent/instance in the JNI could also be a solution to tag the intent with?

Comment: Not that it brings a solution to your question, but adds some pepper to it: it allows to show separately in the "recent apps" screen, the documents that are opened in the same app, see [**ActivityManager.AppTask**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.AppTask.html).

Answer (score 5):

Jan

We have similar problems with JNI objects in our application. The problem is that JNI link isn't work as ordinary Java object and has to be relesed explicitly. At the same time we have activity that can be destroyed at any moment by Android.

Our current solution is to store JNI objects on Application level with posibility to manage refereces and drop objects as soon as reference is zero. And also destroyed JNI reference if activity is going to be destroyed forever. So this is similar like you did in previous post.

However if you would like to have your application scalable after some time you might understand that this solution isn't ideal.

The first thing that Android system sometimes temprorary destroys activity to save memory. In your case all JNI objects with documents will still consume memory. So the best solution here is to be able documents on JNI level saves its state to bundle. This is especually important if your documents can be changed by user. In that case by saving state of JNI object in onSaveInstanceState you can destroy your JNI object and recreate in onCreate. However here it is important to analize how much time is required to destroy/create JNI object with saved to bundle document as we have to support quickly activity recreation in some case (portrait/landscape mode for example) with some limited bundle (not more 1Mb). In case of long process this solution might be not good.
Also as you would like to have one task - one document system. You should consider case when you have several activities in one task.

The second item that Android isn't call onDestroy() always. And if you do some save operation here data might be lost sometimes.

Hope this information helps you.

Comment: First comment to this answer is that I want multiple separate instances (app, gmail  etc initiated) and I like the opportunity to have multiple stacked tasks in an instance (like starting a number of work files from a file manager app). However I think this talk thread is as interesting for those who wants single tasks and single instances. It is not an issue of is it possible but the best practice doing it considering the different aspects of a running Android OS environment and developer community. I am very happy reading your answer.

Comment: There is one Java segment and one JNI segment in a running Android OS environment. The OS might destroy an app or task for the need of the memory, but as far as I can see it never tells it is the reason, it just destroys. There are no messages of such kind in the JNI. However my solution kills the JNI-task (set of document data) if the onDestroy() is combined with  if(isFinishing()) because it is never expected to be restored. All data of the task is released. However if if(isFinishing()) is negative the JNI data is kept and the task is expected to be possibly (most likely) to be restored.

Comment: This works perfectly well, the key is synchronising the task with the JNI data. But if the OS is not sending there will be a leakage of memory in the Android OS environment that I understand is un unhandable for the app, if not told to destroy by any means, data will just be kept? This must be an OS issue rather than an app issue. Or what can the app developer do?

Comment: The issue of unsaved data is not that sour to handle. It is to a large extent a user relation issue. Either the app save at once by data change or letting the user have the responsibility to push the save button. In the end we comes to cases like if the entire unit is rebooted like the user is pulling the battery. In fact I think there is nothing to do there. Rather I worry about what happens if the unit crashes by saving and getting an unrecoverable file loss. Could save a temp-file work copy on disk that is updated first? This is not the issue of the topic here, I assume?

Comment: I think it is important to keep the responsibilities within the casting, an app developer should be responsible for the app, the OS developer for the OS and not mix. I have been in computers since 1984 by the IBM PC1 and XT age and all app developer attempts to solve issues of the OS party, has made the apps unusable very quick and to huge problems for the users. If there is a memory leakage due to failing destroy messages by the OS, let it be. Also I decided to make minSdkVersion=14 to avoid the previous memory fuzz. New machines have a lot of memory and should not be an issue.

Comment: I am an old C-fox and love the direct coding, my mentor back in the 80ies was an assembler star, When the PC came I worked for a bank and their mainframe guys watched and "Reboot a computer??!!?" as it is an impossible thought. Java looks like C but to a large extent is a completely different animal to pamper. Some is quite smooth in Java like the this.recreate();-way of just rewriting the screen for a JNI app. I have no data in the Java part and the amazing rebooting of the user interface is a rational way of having one routine getting it all right. If the OS do it flipping the screen I can.

Comment: Please consider the follow use case: user open document and do some change in this document. Then either press sleep button on its mobile device or just remain motionless. In that case Android go to sleep mode and all applications stopped.

Comment: Let look at Android documentation:_When your activity receives a call to the onStop() method, it's no longer visible and should release almost all resources that aren't needed while the user is not using it. Once your activity is stopped, the system might destroy the instance if it needs to recover system memory. In extreme cases, the system might simply kill your app process without calling the activity's final onDestroy() callback, so it's important you use onStop() to release resources that might leak memory. _

Comment: _Although the onPause() method is called before onStop(), you should use onStop() to perform larger, more CPU intensive shut-down operations, such as writing information to a database._  In other words user might loose his data by just leave unit alone.  We can speculate about such behaviour, but this is how Android works.

Comment: Moreover I observed that if you sleep your phone and you have currently landscape mode Android OS change your applicaiton to portrait mode (after application is stopped) with fully activity recreation, even if your limit your application with landscape mode only.  So you should be ready that if your application is stopped it can destroy activity instance at any moment.  I can only say that mobile OS unlike OS for PC is intended for working with limited number of memory and processor resources and idea to unload application at any moment after user stop to interract with it might be reasonable.

Comment: As I know using multiple instances of the same application in Android is prohibited. But if you would like to switch between the documents you can use multiple tasks approach like [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/recents.html). From user point view it would be the same.

Comment: Very good reading, cant vote again for your answer. Very good topics to thing carefully over. 1.) Well I started in environments when people cheered getting 128K memory to share for 5 users in a DEC PDP and a debate if a PC should have 256K or 320K as standard in the bank. Learned programming in C in DOS where you must write IO directly to the graphics board to have any performance. The issues of mobile phone resources are indeed different from PCs but not that big, compared to the past. I indeed understand the topic but for instance 1,5Gb TAB3 standard test unit, is a lot of memory.

Comment: I am even impressed by the processor performance in JNI not that much worse than a w7 i5 in Windows, however always the Java has different performance. This means that it is quite an option to evacuate memory on the onStop() callback that is absolutely considerable. Even writing a tempfile, when changes are made, I will make some serious studies of my app that way. But extinguish the task without sending onDestroy()/isFinishing()=true; must be seen as a pure OS bug.  An OS bug that in pure Java will not be noticeable but in JNI is only one message, I kill you but I don't want your JNI memory.

Comment: The  this.recreate();-concept is in fact very smooth and solves a lot of situations, like the scenario you describe. My app reappear in the wrong direction but the OS kills and ask for rewrite it, quite right, no problem. I ma getting more and more convinced this is the smooth way of doing it in Android Java+JNI apps as long as all data is in the JNI section and tasks are having separate memory slots in the JNI. Here we are coming back to one of my initial question, is the Intent.EXTRA_TEXT the best practice or is another flag better to store the task ID info? Not used else for such apps.

Comment: You also put up the question, if the OS extinguish the app after onStop() callback an idea could be storing a tempfile by onStop(); But will a killed app ever reappear, for instance holding the home button and select previous instances? If not the issue of what is possibly done not that rich in alternatives, main question is how to use the remains if stored in a temp-file? And if storing a temp file the temp file name should be saved in the intents extra, and what tag is good practice for that? We come back to a need not predicted when the intent extra-tags were made.

Comment: Multiple instances for one app? Well that must be a matter of viewing the topic? If I start my app and open a doc and then go to the ES file handler app and open 5 docs of my type one after another, I get a stack of six tasks, or? Then if I go to the gmail and read a mail with one doc of mine appended to it, and I open it, I get a seventh task, but on another instance, don't I? In my app they are all a stack of tasks, but running the/flipping inbetween they certainly behaves like an on instance in the gmail? Vocabulary, or have I missed something? The gmail task is possible to get instantly.

Comment: Tab3 is good question, but if you would like to have your application work on different devices in Google market you should considered device with 500MB or even less. Activity stopped when it wasn't became visible to user. However if you have at least one pixel that is visible through transparent window of currently visible activity, previous activity isn't stoped only resumed.

Comment: As I understand you would like to save "iInstance" value in case of activity recreation. If this is case the correct way to do it is: 1. Save it as field of activity java class in onCreate in case of savedInstanceState == null, otherwise restore iInstance from savedInstanceState.getInt(...). For String key it is good practice to use string specific for your value, like "packageName.ClassName.fieldName". 2. Save it in onSaveInstanceState to bundle with the same key. Please look [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) for details.

Comment: If user select home button and select different task/application. You activity is stoped and can be destroyed by OS. In that case it saves to bundle it's state in OnSaveInstanceState. Size of bundle in that case isn't officially limited, but based on experiments it can be very big, unlike bundle that is used for exchanging information between different activities. When user try to return back to it's activity OS restarted it by providing all stored information in budle in OnCreate and OnRestoreInstanceState.

Comment: For storing information to bundle you can use any key you want, but good practice to make it specific to information and activities (use package name for example)  For you case you can for example save temp file name to bundle in OnSaveInstantState. In OnStop save temp file itself and restore document OnCreate using temp file name restored from bundle.

Comment: If your app, ES file handler app nad gmail app are differents apps (have different application namespace) and for each document you will create separate task, you correct about seven tasks. I hope I answer on all your question. As your question has an open bounty, you can manually award the bounty to my answer.

Comment: Jan, thank you. I used to develop on Win32 as well and understand your confusion as well. Please don't hesitate to ask me any question.

Comment: It is about tasks not instances mainly here. A slight confusion I vocabulary. In Win32 all this is about "instances", here there are "instances", "tasks" and "activities". I like to store the "taskId", actually the ID od the data of the task I have in the JNI. The instance is handled here by the OS and I only need to keep track of the tasks, works fine. And they can be stacked and they can be from other instances (other apps calling my app), behaves in the app the same for all tasks. Works fine. I think you should make a separate answer on this so I can vote for it?

Comment: On the issue of the OS extinguishing the task without onDestroy()-issue, the main question is "Is it possible to get back to an extinguished task by for instance holding the home button (I don't know how to provoke this scenario to test it)? If not there is nothing to restore I guess, if yes there is and a tempfile approach is a good idea. Second question is if it is practically possible to put up a "Do you want to save the file?" message (make a new activity when leaving the app) when unsaved data exists and there is a onStop() message?

Comment: I have a "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?" so we can flip to the chat for the time being, but really we are talking about the core of the original question. We might should make new questions?

Answer (score 3):

**I made something working but I don't know if it is good practice?**

I am getting an int-instance-tag from JNI and tagging it on the intent by

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
....
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    // Creating the JNI task and get the JNI task ID 
    int iInstance = initProgram(...);
    // and store the JNI task ID in the intent
    getIntent().putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, iInstance);
    ...
} 
    ...

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (JniManagement.resumeInstance(iTask)) {
    ...

public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState); 
    // Restore state members from saved instance 
    iTask =
      savedInstanceState.getInt(AndroidApp.STATE_TASK_ID); 
}
```

Then we are talking about the lifespan of a task, the user is flip/flopping between windows/tasks with the home button. The issue is to synchronise the JNI data with the task of Java.

Re-appearing in th else section of if (savedInstanceState == null) { we get the JNI task ID from the intent and synchronise the JNI task with it.

And onDestroy() with if(isFinishing()) freeing the instance set of memory in the JNI.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();  // Always call the superclass
    if(isFinishing())
        Commands.destroyInstance(getIntent().getExtras().getInt(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, 0));
    // Extinguishing the JNI task started during onCreate()
}
```

**The JNI-side**

In the JNI-side all memory used by an instance will be put together in a structure. This structure could be pointed at, in an array of pointers to get the right set of data for the right instance integer. The pointer array is realloced when new instances are created and can go on as long there is memory left for a new instance.

This works actually pretty good, always getting the right data to the right activity/instance. And using a File Manager app starting one activity after another by calling work data files, there will be a stack of activities/instances. When the user is leaving them with the end button are pealed off one by one and its memory is extinguished real smooth. Open a file in a Gmail works fine too the same way, however appears as a different activity by the activity button.

As an old Win32 C-fox I love my pointers and set them in all the methods/functions this feels a bit clumsy (only handle the active window screen data). But the Android OS do not have active overlapping windows.

***So just synchronising the JNI this way to the right Java activity/instance is simply working real smooth.***

**But is it good practice? Are there any other smooth and good looking solutions?**

Comment: Keep track task affinity for your activity, if you want to control the way different documents are opened in your app from different sources.

Comment: Thanks for the intellectual hint, read quite a lot about instances, tasks and activities. We are actually talking about tasks with activities that are stacked. In practice started by external apps intents that sometimes creates new instances. Else the app could be a single task app. However I like it to have stacked sessions initiated from a File manager app (like ES File handler) or in own instances like launching it from a appended file in Gmail. The standards settings what I have is what I want. Smooth way of interacting with other apps and my app is to a large extent a file browser.

Comment: And the construction described in my answer actually do work very well there, re-synchronise right with the JNI task data handling (an array of pointers to the entire set of data for the task) whenever a task is re-activated (regardless if they are own instances in the Android language. Works real smooth with a minimum code in the Java section.  Had to do some work in the JNI section but that solved multiple "tasks" in other OS environments as well. For instance using the code for a HTML service server (most likely in a completely different OS).

Comment: I think even using the intents are a real sooth solution that looks to be completely coherent to the Android architecture and policies (more than I originally thought). Tagging the intent is a smooth way, and as my app is constructed there is an intent to every new task I deal with. I really wonder how the pure Java app programmers solve this issue?

Comment: **The only thing that bathers me** today is that the flag of the data string Intent.EXTRA_TEXT is there for a completely different use. However a use that never will be used in relation to my app (even from external apps). But it feels like a quick-fix solution. However I can't find any other way of tagging the intent with an ID being able to distinguish it from any other tasks (and intents).

Comment: I believe that [ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo.id](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo.html#id) could be used here.

Comment: Any idea? Looks like a good alternative but I can't get it working, this crashes List<ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRecentTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE, ActivityManager.RECENT_IGNORE_UNAVAILABLE); And this require too high API level (21 use 14): List<ActivityManager.AppTask> recentTasks = activityManager.getAppTasks();

Comment: Well the tasks or instances (dependent on what programming language talk we refer to) are not stacked but numbered. Meaning any task/instance can be activated, comes as the TaskId on the recreation of the Android App `public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        // Restore state members from saved instance
        iTask = savedInstanceState.getInt(AndroidApp.STATE_TASK_ID);
    }`

This means that the solution is not dependent on the stack, any task of the 'stack' can be restored, the user reactivated.